# How can I add a second hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

As seen, an SSD and a 1TB HDD, I'd like to be able to install games and programs on the bigger drive but I don't know how to? I tried changing my steam downloads location to `/dev/sdc3` but it says that a steam library there doesn't exist?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount the drive in 'disks' application before using it in applications.

- Open Disks.
- Click the hard drive
- Select the partition and click gear icon
- Go into edit mount options
- Check mount at startup
- select /dev/sdc3 and the mount Point field above it will have the mount path

Use that mount path in all applications.

Comment: Wow! that was surprisingly easy! Thank you so much! Is it possible to remove the "activities" layer at the top of the screen? It overlaps with whatever i have open on my monitor and it is quite distracting.

Comment: @GottaSlay Yes if you are using gnome desktop environment, you can use this extension which have the option to intellihide or completely hide the top bar.
[Hide Top Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/)